# PHP foreach Check which post so far

Tags: php, date, foreach

Using for each I am dismantling a series of dates.

```
foreach( $ds as $d){

echo '<div class="bkback" onclick="bkdates(this);">'.date('M', strtotime("today + $d day")).'<br /><span class="bknum">'.date('d', strtotime("today + $d day")).'</span><br />
'.date('D', strtotime("today + $d day")).'</div>';

}
```

What I want to do is every put a marker `<div class="marker"></div>` after post 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, and 85 for the purposes of a jumping Jquery scroller.

So I need away of identifying which post we are at so far.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Comment: There is no "posts" in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increment a variable each time through the loop - something like:

```
$i = 0;
foreach( $ds as $d) {
    if ($i++ % 5 == 0) {
        echo '<div class="marker"></div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you need "==" and not "=" in the comparison?

Answer (score 0):

I would just increment a counter and then check to see if it's divisible by 5.

```
$acounter = 0;
foreach( $ds as $d){
  $acounter++;
  if ( $acounter % 5 == 0 ) echo '<div class="marker"></div>';

  echo '<div class="bkback" onclick="bkdates(this);">'.date('M', strtotime("today + $d day")).'<br /><span class="bknum">'.date('d', strtotime("today + $d day")).'</span><br />'.date('D', strtotime("today + $d day")).'</div>';

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$counter = 0;

foreach( $ds as $d){

echo '<div class="bkback" onclick="bkdates(this);">'.date('M', strtotime("today + $d day")).'<br /><span class="bknum">'.date('d', strtotime("today + $d day")).'</span><br />
'.date('D', strtotime("today + $d day")).'</div>';

$counter++;

if ($counter % 5 == 0) { echo '<div class="marker"></div>'; }

}
```